# angles of a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle whose center is $O$. We know that $ \widehat{AOB}=90^\circ$, $ \widehat{BOC}= 60^\circ$, $ \widehat{COD}= 140^\circ$. Determine $\angle{A}$, $\angle{B}$, $\angle{C}$ and $\angle{D}$.

I really can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: What does $\hat{A}$ mean?

Comment: @N.Owad Probably angle $\widehat{BAD}$.

Comment: right, the angle described by AB and AC

Comment: and the same for the others

Answer (score 2):

The triangles from the center are isoceles, it is a trivial matter to compute their two other angles. Then add these pairwise.

Comment: Hence one should be able to solve it...right?

Comment: Give me your results...i don't know their "sides"

Comment: Could you pleaseeee write all the steps?

Comment: Draw a figure, you'll see that the question is trivial.

Comment: true...how to prove it?

Comment: omg oblique sides are equal...

Comment: you're formidable

Comment: Too glad I could help.